# Civilization 6 keeps crashing Windows 10

Tags: technical-issues, civilization-6, windows-10

Specs:

1. Lenovo P50 laptop - 24GB RAM, Nvidia Quadro M1000M
2. Windows 10 Pro - version 22H2, build 19045.2486
3. Civilization 6 (Gathering Storm)
4. Personal machine
5. No 3rd party antivirus, just Microsoft defender
6. Occurs with DirectX 11 and 12

I've tried all of the troubleshooting options I can think of - updating/reinstalling drivers, setting the game graphics to the minimum (i.e. lowest resource usage), ensuring nothing else is running on the laptop, but Civilization 6 still crashes Windows after about 10-15minues of play. The event viewer doesn't show any Criticals or Errors to investigate, just the "The previous system shutdown at 7:31:28 PM on ‎1/‎15/‎2023 was unexpected." after restarting.

Other than Civilization 6, the machine seems to run fine. I don't see any other stability or performance problems running anything else, which mostly entails coding programs like VS Code, docker, power automate desktop.

How can I troubleshoot/isolate the problem here?

Comment: Is this a work laptop controlled by an organization? Does it have any kind of special anti-virus software that you can control?

Comment: @TimmyJim - not a work laptop,this is my own personal machine.  Also, no 3rd party AV, just Microsoft defender.  I just updated the description to add these points

Comment: There are a few threads/propsed solutions on general issues with Civ 6 crashes. 
Might be worth checking some of them. This  one in particular could be a good start: 
https://steamcommunity.com/app/289070/discussions/0/3453716776424294825/

Comment: @swv I think this may be more of a computer error question rather than something about the game itself.

Comment: Are you running with DirectX 11 or 12? I had issues with DX 12 that resolved themselves after switching to 11.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas - Updated to state that it crashes with both DirectX 11 and 12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an answer, but to close this out...
I ended up doing a fresh reinstall of Windows (for a few reasons) and never encountered this problem since.

Answer (score 0):

The case when the game is loading, but crashes when loading the menu, save, new game. This is a common situation that is related to developer problems and you cannot fix it. Will have to wait for a patch.

The third possible case - Sid Meier's Civilization 6 crashes during gameplay, after some action. This is also a common situation and everyone needs to wait for a patch from the developers that will solve the problem.

The developers themselves also believe that running Civilization 6 as an administrator, or using the “windowed” or “frameless” image display mode, instead of full-screen mode, can solve the problem with crashes.
Perhaps you have 2 video cards installed - in this case, disable the secondary one, Civilization 6 does not yet support SLI / CrossFire profiles. If you are playing on a laptop, then try switching from the integrated video card to a dedicated one, at least you should find out which video card the game is running on.

Answer (score 0):

Does it crash with a completely new game or only when it was loaded from a previous save?

The reason I ask is that I've hit a bug which essentially blue screens (without actual blue - goes into a mad spin, you hear audio noise and Win reboots in about 15 min) and the only solution was to go for a new game and latter never to leave a loaded complex/big came sitting idle for a long time. I claim the bug to be a Win 10 bug (it started after a particular force fed update - before that I used to keep Civ 6 lingering/waiting for days, weeks ...)